# Why std::overload instead of concepts/constexpr if in std::visit?

Tags: c++, variant, c++-concepts, c++20

I may be a bit confused about std::overloaded proposal and or concepts, but with my current understanding of both I have the following question:

Why C++20 does not just conceptify/if constexprify std::visit so it knows what to do based on types of arguments passed to it.

For example why can't we have std::visit that modifies it behavior based on concepts of arguments passed(all it requires is that functions go first, variants last).

So for example both of these `visit`s accept 3 arguments but have different logic.

```
    std::variant<int, double> v1=4.7;
    std::variant<bool, std::string> v2=false;
    // calls lambda that is a better fit(double one)
    std::visit([](int& a){std::cout<< sizeof (a);},[](double& a){std::cout << a;} , v1); 
    // calls lambda on variant v1 and then variant v2
    std::visit([](auto& a){}, v1, v2);
```

Comment: It will make the implementation even more complicated (and it's already very complicated). I don't think the benefit matches the added complication.

Comment: What cpplearner said. Also, having `std::visit([](auto& a){}, v1, v2);` compile seems actively bad. (Maybe there's some confusion here - note that it does not compile [today](https://godbolt.org/z/fG4cnP)).

Comment: @Barry why then cppreference has Variants... as template type in signature of std::visit? rephrased: how to make it compile...

Comment: ah nvm, visitor should take 2 arguments... I was wrong. editing Q

Comment: but that being said visit could still deduce arity of visitors and match them against variants just fine. :)

Comment: @cpplearner for the specific case of `std::visit` this might be correct, under a certain understanding of what is more complicated or less so.  However, I'm being drawn more and more to the technique of using `if constexpr` instead of overloading.

Answer (score 7):

I think this would be a very bad idea.

`visit` right now is conceptually a straightforward function. It does this:

```
template <typename F, typename... Variants>
decltype(auto) visit(F f, Variants... vs) {
    return f(std::get<vs.index()>(vs)...);
}
```

Except of course `vs.index()` isn't a constant expression so you can't just do that, you need this whole complex implementation to make that work. But the point is - `visit`ing a bunch of variants just invokes `f` on the current alternatives of each one. That's straightforward to reason about.

Having a generic algorithm do semantically different things based on the types it's passed is a very bad idea. It means you can't really reason about the correctness of your code - because it could do basically anything. The last example in the OP is a good example of this:

```
std::visit([](auto&){}, v1, v2);        // #1
std::visit([](auto&, auto&){}, v1, v2); // #2
```

Today, `#1` (the OP example) does not compile because you're passing a unary function to a binary visitor. This is a good thing. But with the suggestion, both would compile and do *wildly* different things. One would visit each variant sequentially, the other would visit each variant together.

What was the user intent? Maybe `#1` was a bug, and the user either forgot an argument or provided a visitor that worked as a binary visitor in most but not all cases but works as a unary visitor in all cases?

---

The other example in the OP is less bad, which is having:

```
visit(f1, f2, f3, v1, v2, v3)
```

mean a ternary visit on three combined functions, rather than a quinary visitor on one function:

```
visit(overload(f1, f2, f3), v1, v2, v3)
```

But that would be very complex to implement, with minimal gain (the user could just wrap the functions on their side right?), and you have to start asking questions like: what if you have an invocable `variant`?

If you're going to go with a different syntax, I've seen several code examples where people implement visitation syntactically like this:

```
visit2(v1, v2, v3)(f1, f2, f3)
```

This is remarkably easy to implement:

```
template <typename... Variants>
auto visit2(Variants&&... variants) {
    return [&](auto&&... fs) -> decltype(auto) {
        return std::visit(overload(FWD(fs)...), FWD(variants)...);
    };
}
```

And has the benefit of putting the variant(s) first and not having to write `overload`. Maybe that's just good enough.

Comment: upvoted, please provide definition of FWD macro for future readers